# Which DB to store weather data generated by weather stations?

Tags: database

I'm developing a server rest that integrates weather data generated by a weather station with an interval of 15 minutes.  I will use the weather data to do several weather forecast. I've a doubt about the best choice to manage them. My questions is:
Which database is more appropriate to store weather data?  the database should grow fast and should keep historical data.

Comment: what format is the data in? what sort of processing do you need to do on it?

Comment: In csv or txt. Then I probably need to process them with python for example forecasting desease

Comment: Were you able to decide upon the database for this? Weather station data isn't huge even when stored in 15 minutes interval. A relational database like MySQL would work for your case unless there is more to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your help. is it also a good practice use json if I have a lot of variables?